# keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format when list command use

Tags: java, windows, jboss, solaris-10

I'm creating a CA using this command in the past worked (1 one week ago) but now It don't works:

`/export/home/java7_8/jre1.7.0_80/bin/keytool -genseckey -alias testvault-keystore /data/jboss/passwd.keystore -storetype jceks -keyalg AES -keysize 128 -storepass pwdtest -keypass pwdtest`

so when I tested the file using this command:

`/export/home/java7_8/jre1.7.0_80/bin/keytool -list -keystore /data/jboss/passwd.keystore`

I received:

`keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format`

I drop the CA and try in many ways using another keystore, also I tried using windows and also I received the same error message.

I want create this CA for use jboss-vault but I can't continue because this error.

FYI: I'm using solaris 10 and windows 7 jre1.7.0_80 and 1.7.0_60 respectively

Someone can help me?

Comment: Probably your keystore is corrupt? Try creating another store and add it to cross verify.

Comment: You need to give the `-storetype jceks`

Comment: i would reccomend you to use key tool explorer, check if your key isnt corrupt and then covert to watever format required.... http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/downloads.php

Comment: Sorry I forgot said that I test using this command:

$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -list -keystore=/data/jboss/passwd.keystore -storetype jceks

and receive the same error message

keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Andreas thanks the parameters is there!

I tested just using:

run $JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/keytool 

keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

So Im going to reinstall the java and try again.

Comment: Hello, I just came to said that the error was for an jre corrupted after reinstall the jre and jdk the error dissapear and also as commented andreas the -storetype jceks is necessary if not the error appears again thanks for the help, was funny that in 2 machines occurs the same error.